# How to reset the action link URL to the initial value in the Firebase auth console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I changed the action link URL just to test the feature but now I need to use the initial value and I don't know how to reset the link.
I tried to change with the initial link but there is an error and nothing change (the error is just a red line with 'something wrong').
Here is the only help from firebase : https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714#actionlink

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset your action code URL, you need to change it back to something like: 
`https://$AUTH_DOMAIN/__/auth/action`

Where `$AUTH_DOMAIN` is the same authDomain you can get from your web snippet. It will look like: example.firebaseapp.com

Comment: I have already tried it but just for this URL, nothing happend when I save the change ...

Comment: What do you mean? Are you unable to save that? What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, yes and no... When I save it, an error message pops out with "an unknown error just happens with the server" (or something like that - mine is in French ...) and then, another pop up says that the save is OK. But when I reload the page, it is my old link which is there. And I try with another link that my initial value link, all was going well.

Comment: Hey Francois, can you provide the network error you are getting?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Al4u8hoba_q0m49cmJzxSicmR5xyzg
It is a the error... in inglish this means "an unknown error just happens with the server"...

Comment: Check in the developer console of the browser. The error there should be more useful. The user facing error is not useful here. You should also reach out to Firebase Support about this.

Comment: I have the same problem, when I try to update the action link URL I get a notification saying "An unknown problem with server..." Then immediately afterwards another notifications says "Action URL has been customized". in the console I get this error: VM929:1 POST https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/m/idtoolkit/setconfig 400

and when you the tabs, the action link URL goes back to the default one.

Comment: Not sure why you are having this issue JC. I tried customizing and reverting the action URL in the Firebase Console and it is working. You may want to file a Firebase support ticket about this: https://firebase.google.com/support/